# Dependant permissions in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

I have a query -

Suppose I have a notebooks (Physics,Chemistry,Math,...) and I want to put note in these notebooks by implementing some permissions -

1. If I have permissions to view notebooks and I must be able to see all/some note books in drop down
2. I should be able to add/delete/view note inside any notebook if I am allowed to access that notebook and allowed to add/delete/view note inside that notebook

What could be best approach to implement this situation best

I walk around stack overflow but did not find any answer regarding it

Comment: You can either implement your [custom per-view permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions) or override `get_queryset` of your view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `get_permissions` class in your view depending on the action being performed, you can also add in your own permission, here is an example working with ModeViewSet.

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action in ['create', 'list', 'retrieve']:
        # Add or View records if you are logged in
        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(),)
    else:
        # Delete or update records if you are logged in and added the record
        return (permissions.IsAuthenticated(), IsOwner(),)
```

IsOwner is coming from a custom permission class in permissions.py as below:

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwner(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user
```

This example custom class checks if the logged in user is the user that created the record assuming there is a user pk in the notebook model.

Also in your user model, you can set `is_staff=True` and user `permissions.IsAdminUser` for users allowed to view the records or create a custom permission class to be based on some user type.